JS images not found in `site:` Google search for static site, despite submission to Google Console
I have a static website with a gallery page, wherein users can search hundreds of images via JavaScript. Every img has a descriptive filename and alt attribute. When searching Google Images for site:my_domain_name.com any describing words here, a few miscellaneous images show from other pages on my website, but none of the JS-searchable gallery images show on Google Images.
To fix this, I first tried listing all image locations in a sitemap.txt file as a plain-text list. Google Console shows the file as indexed. But none of the gallery images show in Console (though I don’t think any ever show there), and none of the gallery images continue to show in Google Images search.
I now tried listing all images in a sitemap-images.xml file, structured like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>https://my_domain_name.com/images/</loc>
        <image:image><image:loc>https://my_domain_name.com/assets/images/gallery/some_image_filename.jpg</image:loc></image:image>
        <image:image><image:loc>https://my_domain_name.com/assets/images/gallery/another_image_filename.jpg</image:loc></image:image>
        [ ...MANY MORE <IMAGE> LINES.. ]
    </url>
</urlset>

Console shows the XML sitemap is indexed. But still, none of these images appear in Console or search. What am I missing? Thank you.

A few thoughts:

Is https://my_domain_name.com/images/ the actual location of your gallery page, ie if a user went to that URL does it return something?
Does the image's filename describe the image in any way?  Google deprecated captions and titles in image sitemaps a couple of years back, which means that if the page isn't embedded on a page, then they have less signals to go on.
Are the images original to your site?
Are the images a reasonable size, and is your sitemap linking to the full size version?
Do you see any of them if you search site:my_domain_name.com without any additional keywords?
How long has it been since you submitted the sitemap?
Are the images AI generated?


The domain name is an example.
All filenames describe the images.
Nearly all images are our original creations.
Nearly all images are presented full size in high resolution.
Removing keywords from search does not reveal the gallery’s images.
Sitemaps were resubmitted last week, but I’ve been retooling them off and on for a year.
No images are AI generations.

Why was this question awarded the bounty? Neither answered my question, but the other answer was more helpful.

Nowt to do with me.

I suspect there is a disconnect between what you are signaling to Google and what they are seeing and that is why they are not indexing/showing your images in the SERPs. Also, if you are leveraging a CDN to deliver your images, this could complicate your situation where you need to claim that domain as well.
You have probably done this already, but I would refer to Google's documentation about SEO for Images and just double check you are following their guidelines.
Potential Issue #1: Dynamic JS gallery is "hiding" the images
I suspect one of the main issues is that Google isn't interacting with your js gallery in a significant way to find your images. I would test your page as Googlebot out of Search Console and see what they are seeing. It could be the entire gallery isn't visible, so in turn none of the images will be.
Do you have other images on your site that are placed directly onto HTML page(s)? Can you search for those directly and they appear in SERPs?
Potential Issue #2: Your image sitemap is technically correct but functionality wrong
Even though the images can be accessed on your https://my_domain_name.com/images/, Google isn't seeing them because they are in a gallery. It could be that Google isn't seeing this connection because they have to "search" in the js gallery to view them. So Google could be assuming this is an incorrect signal and disregarding it in their indexing process.
I would start with viewing the page in Search Console and see what they see when Googlebot requests your page. It could be the JavaScript library used for the gallery. It could be the tags used to display the images within the gallery. It could be a host of other things, but I would start with the crawl and work your way forward.
Edit:
Potential Solution(s)
With the added information of volume of images, and not doing a whole lot of research on this, I think there could be some solution. Granted, there are various levels of pain involved with each.
One of the main questions to be answered by you / your client is what the end goal of organic reach is? Are you trying to sell all the different images to people? Are you only wanting to show in image results to get people on the site? Depending on your goal, one solution might be more appealing than the other.
SEO Focused Javascript Libraries
This is probably a common problem for people who have large libraries of images and want to provide them to users for consumption. There might be some more SEO focused / aware options for you to dynamically present the images AND include filtering capabilities. I have never attempted something like this so it may / may not be available.
Focused "Category" Pages / Sub Pages
Knowing that you have ~700+ images that you are wanting to present to users, you could break those down into topographical groups. You have mentioned filters, so you might already have a workable structure.
With the structure developed, you could create category pages that display the images within each category. Something like https://my-site.com/images/category and use those as a gallery page. You could break it down further with https://my-site.com/images/category/sub-category as well.
With this solution, I would 100% recommend having a lazy loading solution to cut down on download times. This probably wouldn't work otherwise.
You could limit the thumbnails you show on the screen to a certain amount and then show the rest at text links with very descriptive click text. That way, the image can be included in the image sitemap and Google crawling the site will still see that image in relation to the url listed.
I fully understand this is a giant undertaking. Implementing lazy loading enough is a large task not to mention building out the information architecture to have category pages for images. But outside of a dynamic, searchable, indexable JavaScript solution it might be the only option.
Mash of the two
A combination of the two could be viable. You could create category landing pages which will display a certain amount of images in the HTML. Then somewhere on the page, you could leverage the JavaScript library so the user can search the entire database. The downside of this is knowing that only those images you list on the page will be indexed rather than your entire library.
Not knowing your sector and/or what you are trying to accomplish with the site, this could be an option. If you/ your client only wants the images to appear in results for eye-catching and lead gathering, it could do that enough to get them on the site and covert.

Thanks for your reply. Our website uses no CDN. How would I “test our site as Googlebot out of Search Console”? Yes, other images on our site appear in Google Images search results, but none from our JS-searchable gallery. How would I “view the page in Search Console and see what they see when Googlebot requests our page”? Our webpage uses no JS library. Our website uses no tags. How would I “start with the crawl”?

In Search Console, use the main search bar and put in the gallery's URL. This will bring up the URL Inspection of the page and it will have a bunch of information on its indexing and also have screenshots and HTML that was captured when it was crawled. There will also be a "Live Test" section where you can request Googlebot to pull your page right then to show you what it sees. I would use this to assess what they are seeing and figure out if the gallery is causing the issue; which I suspect it does based on your above reply.

Interesting. The live test offers a screenshot, and it shows images, but only the first five, as if viewed on a phone without scrolling very far.

Our gallery has over 700 images, with more coming. The gallery initially shows 24 random images, with a button to show more, with a dropdown to filter by type, and with a text input to search. To put all 700 images in the DOM on pageload would be a huge hit to users. How can I get search engines to find our images?

I updated my main response with potential solutions. Granted, these are on the fly ideas that might not work for your site or might not be available at all.

Thank you for your continued correspondence. If I were to “create category pages”, then users would need to navigate between several different pages. Having them filterable and searchable all on one page requires no inter-page navigation, and is therefore the better UX.

“…what the end goal of organic reach is? Are you trying to sell all the different images to people? Are you only wanting to show in image results to get people on the site?” The latter. We are a nonprofit, selling nothing. But many people are searching the web for our infographics, maps, and memes, which are not showing in Google Images.

I agree, it will cause the user to work harder to find what they are wanting. This extra effort is to increase the visibility of the images (and content) in organic listings and have it properly indexed by search engines. Def a trade off for those things ranking. This might not work with your goals as an organization. You can somewhat mitigate this by strategically cross linking category pages. This would probably require deep dive into user analytics and see how people are looking at engaging with the gallery.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

We add images weekly. Our last crawl was today, and before that Monday (neither by our request).

I don’t know why Stack awarded points to the other answerer. I emailed Stack to ask why, but I have yet to get a reply. Holidays might be delaying them.

I stopped receiving notifications for this question from Stack. I don’t know why, sometimes emails from Stack just stop for a few months.
